# How does Stack Exchange log you in when you're logged into Stack Overflow?

Tags: authentication

My guess is: SO includes some sort of `<img src="stack exchange URL" />` right when I log in with a one-time token or something. Can somebody tell me how it actually works?

Comment: See also [How does SO's new auto-login feature work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Stack Overflow blog post on [Global Network Auto-Login](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) explains how this happens. Essentially it uses [HTML 5 storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) combined with a central authentication site at http://stackauth.com.

Comment: They say on stackauth.com that Firefox 3.6+ are supported, but I'm in Firefox 3.5.13 and it works just fine. They must have back ported the storage API to Firefox 3.5. I love Firefox :)