# How to redirect from one domain to another and set cookies or headers for the other domain?

Tags: python, redirect, cookies, cross-domain, fastapi

I am using FastAPI's [`RedirectResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/es/advanced/custom-response/#redirectresponse) and trying to redirect the user from one application (domain) to another with some cookie set in the `response`; however, the cookie always gets deleted/not transferred. If I try to add some headers, all the headers that I add to the `RedirectResponse` are not transferred either.

```
@router.post("/callback")
async def sso_callback(request: Request):
   jwt_token = generate_token(request)
   redirect_response = RedirectResponse(url="http://192.168.10.1/app/callback", 
                             status_code=303)
   redirect_response.set_cookie(key="accessToken", value=jwt_token, httponly=True)
   redirect_response.headers["Authorization"] = str(jwt_token)
   return redirect_response
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 21):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) you cannot redirect to another domain with custom headers set, no matter what language or framework you use. A redirection in the HTTP protocol is basically a header (i.e., [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location)) associated with the response, and it doesn't allow for any headers to the target location to be added. When you add the `Authorization` header in your example, you basically set that header for the response which is instructing the browser to redirect, not for the redirect itself. In other words, you are sending that header **back to the client**.

As for the [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), the browser stores the cookies sent by the server with the response (using the [`Set-Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header), and later sends the cookies with requests made to the **same server** inside a [`Cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) HTTP header. As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie):

> The `Set-Cookie` HTTP response header is used to send a cookie from
> the server to the user agent, so that the user agent can send it back
> to the server later. To send multiple cookies, multiple `Set-Cookie`
> headers should be sent in the same response.

Hence, if this was a redirection from one app (with sub-domain, e.g., `abc.example.test`) to another (with sub-domain, e.g., `xyz.example.test`) that both have the same (parent) domain (and the `domain` flag was set to `example.test` when creating the cookies), cookies would be successfully shared between the two apps (as [if `domain` is specified, then subdomains are always included](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent)). The browser will make a cookie available to the given domain including any sub-domains, no matter which protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) or port is used. You can limit a cookie's availability using the `domain` and `path` flags, as well as [restrict access to the cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) with `secure` and `httpOnly` flags (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_data_storage_access) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain), as well as [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie)). If the `httpOnly` flag isn't set, a potential attacker can read and modify the information through JavaScript (JS), whereas a cookie with the `httpOnly` attribute is only sent to the server, and is inaccessible to JS on client side.

However, [you **cannot** set cookies for a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6761443/17865804). If this was permitted, it would present an enormous security flaw. Hence, since you are *"trying to redirect the user from one application (domain) to another with some cookie set,..."*, it wouldn't work, as the cookie will only be sent with requests made to the **same domain**.

### Solution 1

A solution, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12370586/17865804), is to have domain (app) A redirecting the user to domain (app) B, with the `access-token` passed in the URL as a query parameter. Domain B would then read the token and set its own cookie, so that the browser will store and send that cookie with every subsequent request to domain B.

Please note that you should consider using a secure (HTTPS) communication, so that the token is transferred encrypted, as well as setting the `secure` flag when creating the cookie. Also, note that having the token in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) **poses a serious security risk**, as sensitive data should never be passed in the query string. This is because the query string, which is part of the URL, appears in the address bar of the browser; thus, allowing the user to see and bookmark the URL with the token in it (meaning that it is saved on the disk). Also, the URL will make it to the [browsing history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browsing_history), which means it will be written to the disk anyway and appear in the `History` tab (press <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> to see the browser's history). Both the above would allow attackers (and people you share the computer/mobile device with) to steal such sensitive data. Additionally, many browser plugins/extensions track users' browsing activity—every URL you visit is sent to their servers for analysis, in order to detect malicious websites and warn you beforehand. Hence, you should take all the above into consideration before using the approach below (for related posts on this subject, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56273618), [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/29598) and [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/142695)).

To prevent displaying the URL in the address bar, the approach below uses a redirection within domain B as well. Once domain B receives the request to the `/submit` route with the token as a query parameter, domain B responds with a redirection to a bare URL with no tokens in it (i.e., its `home` page). Because of this redirection, the URL with the token in it wouldn't end up in the browsing history. Although this provides some protection against certain attacks described earlier, it doesn't mean that browser extensions, etc., won't still be able to capture the URL with the token in it.

If you are testing this on localhost, you need to give application B a different domain name; otherwise, as mentioned earlier, cookies will be shared between applications having the same domain, and hence, you would end up receiving the cookies set for domain A, and couldn't tell if the approach is working at all. To do that, you have to edit the `/etc/hosts` file (on Windows this is located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) and assign a hostname to `127.0.0.1`. For example:

```
127.0.0.1 example.test
```

You shouldn't add the scheme or port to the domain, as well as shouldn't use common extensions, such as `.com`, `.net`, etc., otherwise it may conflict with accessing other websites on the Internet.

Once you access domain A below, you will need to click on the `submit` button to perform a `POST` request to the `/submit` route to start the redirection. The only reason for the `POST` request is because you are using it in your example and I am assuming you have to post some `form-data`. Otherwise, you could use a `GET` request as well. In app B, when performing a `RedirectResponse` from a `POST` route (i.e., `/submit`) to a `GET` route (i.e., `/`), the response status code changes to `status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777217/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73088816/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693108/17865804). App A is listening on port `8000`, while app B is listening on port `8001`.

Run both apps below, and then access domain A at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

**appA.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()
           
@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Click the "submit" button to be redirected to domain B</h2>
          <form method="POST" action="/submit">
             <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
        
@app.post("/submit")
def submit():
    token = 'MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3'
    redirect_url = f'http://example.test:8001/submit?token={token}'
    response = RedirectResponse(redirect_url)
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True)  # set cookie for domain A too
    return response
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**appB.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def home(request: Request):
    token = request.cookies.get('access-token')
    print(token)
    return 'You have been successfully redirected to domain B!' \
           f' Your access token ends with: {token[-4:]}'
 
@app.post('/submit')
def submit(request: Request, token: str):
    redirect_url = request.url_for('home')
    response = RedirectResponse(redirect_url, status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True)
    return response
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```

### Solution 2

Another solution would be to use [`Window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), which enables `cross-origin` communication between [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) objects; for example, between a page and a `pop-up` that it spawned, or between a page and an `iframe` embedded within it. Examples on how to add event listeners and communicate between the windows can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#examples). The steps to follow would be:

**Step 1:** Add to domain A a hidden `iframe` to domain B. For example:

```
<iframe id="cross_domain_page" src="http://example.test:8001" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background:transparent;margin:auto;display:block"></iframe>
```

**Step 2:** As soon as you obtain the `Authorization` token from the headers of an [asynchronous JS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to domain A, send it to domain B. For example:

```
document.getElementById('cross_domain_page').contentWindow.postMessage(token,"http://example.test:8001");
```

**Step 3:** In domain B, receive the token through `window.addEventListener("message", (event) ...` , and store it in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem('token', event.data);
```

or, in a cookie using JS (not recommended, see notes below):

```
document.cookie = `token=${event.data}; path=/; SameSite=None; Secure`;
```

**Step 4:** Message domain A that the token has been stored, and then redirect the user to domain B.

**Note 1:** Step 3 demonstrates how to set a cookie using JS, but you **shouldn't really use** JS when you are about to store such sensitive information, as [cookies created via JS can't include the `HttpOnly` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#define_where_cookies_are_sent), which helps mitigate cross-site scripting ([XSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#cross-site_scripting_(xss))) attacks. This means that attackers who may have injected malicious scripts into your website would be able to access the cookie. You should rather **let the server set the cookie** (through a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) request), including the `HttpOnly` flag (as shown in the example below), thus making the cookie inaccessible to the JS [`Document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) API. The `localStorage` is also susceptible to XSS attacks, as the data are also accessible via JS (e.g., `localStorage.getItem('token')`).

**Note 2:** For this solution to work, users must have the option `Allow all cookies` enabled in their browsers—that many users don't, as well as some browsers exclude **third-party** cookies by default (Safari and In Private mode of Chrome are known for rejecting these cookies by default)—as the content is being loaded into an `iframe` from a different domain, and thus the cookie is [classed as a **third-party** cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117271). The same applies to using `localStorage` as well (i.e., `Allow all cookies` must be enabled for being able to use it through an `iframe`). Using cookies in this case, however, you would also need to set the `SameSite` flag to `None`, as well as the cookie should include the `Secure` flag, [which is required in order to use `SameSite=None`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite#samesitenone_requires_secure). This means that the cookie will only be sent over [HTTPS](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/https/) connections; this won't mitigate all risks associated with cross-site access, but it will provide protection against network attacks (if your server does not run over HTTPS, for demo purposes only, you can use the `'Insecure origins treated as secure'` experimental feature at `chrome://flags/` in Chrome browser). Setting `SameSite=None` means that the cookie **would not be protected** from external access, and you should thus be aware of the risks before using it.

##### Example using `iframe` and `SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly` cookie

Run both apps below, and then access domain A at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

**appA.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Click the "submit" button to be redirected to domain B</h2>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"><br>
          <iframe id="cross_domain_page" src="http://example.test:8001/iframe"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background:transparent;margin:auto;display:block"></iframe>
          <script>
             function submit() {
                fetch('/submit', {
                     method: 'POST',
                  })
                  .then(res => {
                     authHeader = res.headers.get('Authorization');
                     if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                        token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);
                     return res.text();
                  })
                  .then(data => {
                     document.getElementById('cross_domain_page').contentWindow.postMessage(token, "http://example.test:8001");
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                     console.error(error);
                  });
             }
             
             window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "http://example.test:8001")
                  return;
             
                if (event.data == "cookie is set")
                  window.location.href = 'http://example.test:8001/';
             }, false);
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
    """

@app.post('/submit')
def submit():
    token = 'MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    response = Response('success', headers=headers)
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True)  # set cookie for domain A too
    return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**appB.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/iframe', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def iframe():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <script>
             window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "http://127.0.0.1:8000")
                   return;
             
                fetch('/submit', {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: {
                         'Authorization': `Bearer ${event.data}`
                      }
                   })
                   .then(res => res.text())
                   .then(data => {
                      event.source.postMessage("cookie is set", event.origin);
                   })
                   .catch(error => {
                      console.error(error);
                   })
             }, false);
          </script>
       </head>
    </html>
    """
    
@app.get('/')
def home(request: Request):
    token = request.cookies.get('access-token')
    print(token)
    return 'You have been successfully redirected to domain B!' \
           f' Your access token ends with: {token[-4:]}'

@app.post('/submit')
def submit(request: Request):
    authHeader = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if authHeader.startswith("Bearer "):
        token = authHeader[7:]
    response = Response('success')
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, samesite='none', secure=True, httponly=True) 
    return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```

##### Example using `iframe` and `localStorage`

This example demonstrates an approach using `localStorage` this time to store the token. As soon as the token is stored, domain A redirects the user to `/redirect` route of domain B; domain B then retrieves the token from the `localStorage` (and subsequently removes it from the `localStorage`), and later sends it to its own `/submit` route, in order to set an `httpOnly` cookie for `access-token`. Finally, the user is redirected to the home page of domain B.

**appA.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()
    
@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Click the "submit" button to be redirected to domain B</h2>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"><br>
          <iframe id="cross_domain_page" src="http://example.test:8001/iframe"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="background:transparent;margin:auto;display:block"></iframe>
          <script>
             function submit() {
                fetch('/submit', {
                     method: 'POST',
                  })
                  .then(res => {
                     authHeader = res.headers.get('Authorization');
                     if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                        token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);
                     return res.text();
                  })
                  .then(data => {
                     document.getElementById('cross_domain_page').contentWindow.postMessage(token, "http://example.test:8001");
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                     console.error(error);
                  });
             }
             
             window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "http://example.test:8001")
                  return;
             
                if (event.data == "token stored")
                  window.location.href = 'http://example.test:8001/redirect';
             }, false);
                
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
    """

@app.post('/submit')
def submit():
    token = 'MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    response = Response('success', headers=headers)
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True)  # set cookie for domain A too
    return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**appB.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/iframe', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def iframe():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <script>
             window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                if (event.origin !== "http://127.0.0.1:8000")
                   return;
             
                localStorage.setItem('token', event.data);
                event.source.postMessage("token stored", event.origin);
             }, false);
          </script>
       </head>
    </html>
    """
 
@app.get('/redirect', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def redirect():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <script>
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem("token");   
            fetch('/submit', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                     'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                  }
               })
               .then(res => res.text())
               .then(data => {
                  window.location.href = 'http://example.test:8001/';
               })
               .catch(error => {
                  console.error(error);
               })
          </script>
       </head>
    </html>
    """
    
    
@app.get('/')
def home(request: Request):
    token = request.cookies.get('access-token')
    print(token)
    return 'You have been successfully redirected to domain B!' \
           f' Your access token ends with: {token[-4:]}'

@app.post('/submit')
def submit(request: Request):
    authHeader = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    if authHeader.startswith("Bearer "):
        token = authHeader[7:]
    response = Response('success')
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True) 
    return response
  
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```

### Solution 3

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743774/how-does-stack-exchange-log-you-in-when-youre-logged-into-stack-overflow) and [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/11/global-network-auto-login/) to see how StackExchange's auto-login works; for example, StackExchange (SE) automatically logs you in when you're already logged in to StackOverflow (SO). In brief, they don't use third-party cookies, but `localStorage` instead combined with global authentication at their centralised domain http://stackauth.com. Even though third-party cookies are not used, they do use `iframe`, as noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64274), to store the token in `localStorage`. That means, this approach will only work if users' browser accepts **third-party** cookies (as described in Solution 2). As explained in Solution 2, even if you are accessing `localStorage` and not `document.cookie` within an `iframe` embedded in the main window, you still need users to have `Allow all cookies` enabled in their browser settings; otherwise, it wouldn't work and users would be asked to log in again, if they attempted to access any other site in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

##### Update

The approach described above is how SE's auto-login used to work in the past. Nowadays, the approach differs a little bit, as described in a more [recent post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312956), which atually describes the way SE's universal login works today (you can verify the process by inspecting the Network activity in the DevTools of your browser, while logging in to one of the SE sites; for instance, SO).

The way it works is by injecting `<img>` tags pointing to the other Stack Exchange sites (i.e., serverfault.com, superuser.com, etc.) when you log in to one of the SE sites. The `src` URL of these  `<img>` tags includes a unique `authToken` as a query parameter that is generated by a universal authentication system and obtained through an `XMLHttpRequest` `POST` request. An example of these `<img>` tags would be the following:

```html
<img src="https://serverfault.com/users/login/universal.gif?authToken=<some-token-value>&nonce=<some-nonce-value>" />
```

You browser will then send that `src` URL (with the `authToken` in it) to each of the other sites (that you're currently not on), and in response of that image, two cookies will be returned for every given domain/site: `prov` and `acct`. When you later switch to one of the other SE sites, your browser will send the cookies `prov` and `acct` that you received earlier, in order for the site to validate the token and (if valid) log you in.

**Note:** For this to work, your browser needs to accept **third-party** cookies (as desctibed earlier), as the cookie has to be set with the `SameSite=None; Secure` flags (be aware of the risks mentioned above). Without allowing third-party cookies—as well as without running your server over HTTPS—universal auto-login won't work. Also, the other domain for which you are trying to set cookies needs to have [CORS](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) enabled, as when the `img` gets loaded from a different domain, a [cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request is performed. Moreover, as this approach sends the `authToken` in the query parameters of the URL (even though it takes place in the background and not in the address bar of the browser), you should be aware of the risks described earlier in Solution 1.

The below uses an `<img>` tag pointing to domain B. The img URL doesn't have to be an actual image for the server to receive the `access-token`, and thus, you can use the `.onerror()` function to check when the request is actually completed (meaning that the server has responded with the `Set-Cookie` header), so that you can redirect the user to domain B.

One could instead use a `fetch` request to domain B with the `access-token` in the `Authorization` header, and the server can respond similarly to set the cookie. In that case, make sure to use [`credentials: 'include'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) and [`mode: 'cors'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode), as well as explicitly specify the allowed origins on server side, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804).

Run both apps below, and subsequently access domain A at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

**appA.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home():
    return """
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <h2>Click the "submit" button to be redirected to domain B</h2>
          <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"><br>
          <script>
            function submit() {
               fetch('/submit', {
                     method: 'POST',
                  })
                  .then(res => {
                     authHeader = res.headers.get('Authorization');
                     if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                        token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);

                     return res.text();
                  })
                  .then(data => {
                     var url = 'http://example.test:8001/submit?token=' + encodeURIComponent(token);
                     var img = document.createElement('img');
                     img.style = 'display:none';
                     img.crossOrigin = 'use-credentials'; // needed for CORS
                     img.onerror = function(){
                        window.location.href = 'http://example.test:8001/';
                     }
                     img.src = url;
                  })
                  .catch(error => {
                     console.error(error);
                  });
            }
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
    """
    
@app.post('/submit')
def submit():
    token = 'MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3'
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
    response = Response('success', headers=headers)
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, httponly=True)  # set cookie for domain A too
    return response
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**appB.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = ['http://localhost:8000', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
           'https://localhost:8000', 'https://127.0.0.1:8000'] 

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get('/')
def home(request: Request):
    token = request.cookies.get('access-token')
    print(token)
    return 'You have been successfully redirected to domain B!' \
           f' Your access token ends with: {token[-4:]}'
 
@app.get('/submit')
def submit(request: Request, token: str):
    response = Response('success')
    response.set_cookie(key='access-token', value=token, samesite='none', secure=True, httponly=True) 
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8001)
```