# Can't get variable from session using SessionMiddleware in FastAPI

Tags: python, session-cookies, fastapi, starlette

I am trying to make a primitive authorization by session, here is a sample code

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string", max_age=0)


@app.get("/a")
async def session_set(request: Request):
    request.session["my_var"] = "1234"
    return 'ok'


@app.get("/b")
async def session_info(request: Request):
    my_var = request.session.get("my_var", None)
    return my_var


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('http-session:app', port=5000, reload=True)
```

The `session` is set, everything is fine, but the `session_info` endpoint returns an empty dictionary. Can you explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't `max_age=0` mean that the cookie expires as soon as it's being set? Have you verified that the cookie is being sent along with the second request?

Comment: I thought that maxage=0 means that the session will be infinite until the user logs out. It turns out you need to set maxage=None to achieve this

Now I changed it, I'm already getting a response, but the session changes with each request to session_info. How to fix it? I need to work with one session and change it only in route session_set

Comment: @MatsLindh https://prnt.sc/cwsZS3h94YM-     https://prnt.sc/rZGR2z_p0rzr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Starlette documentation on `SessionMiddleware`](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware):

- ...
- `max_age` - Session expiry time in seconds. Defaults to 2 weeks. If
  set to `None` then the cookie will last as long as the browser session.
- `same_site` - SameSite flag prevents the browser from sending session
  cookie along with cross-site requests. Defaults to `'lax'`.
- `https_only` - Indicate that Secure flag should be set (can be used
  with HTTPS only). Defaults to `False`.

Hence, using  `max_age=0` simply results in the `session` cookie getting instantly expired (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74060795/17865804) as well). You can either remove `max_age` when calling `app.add_middleware()` function, or adjust it as desired. Additionally, you may consider adjusting the `same_site` and `https_only` flags as well, in order to provide some protecttion to the `session` cookie (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804) for more details).

Comment: I thought that maxage=0 means that the session will be infinite until the user logs out. It turns out you need to set maxage=None to achieve this Now I changed it, I'm already getting a response, but the session changes with each request to session_info. How to fix it? I need to work with one session and change it only in route session_set   prnt.sc/cwsZS3h94YM- prnt.sc/rZGR2z_p0rzr

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Help me there please  ! Its other problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897479/fastapi-set-new-session-every-request

Comment: i mark your answer

Comment: https://prnt.sc/0r_vnTSOPVxM

Comment: Can you help me there too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73897479/fastapi-sets-new-session-for-every-request

Comment: When max_age is set to None , it throws error TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not NoneType.

Comment: @elyte5star update your version of starlette/fastapi. I had the same issue.