# FastAPI/Starlette's SessionMiddleware creates new session for every request

Tags: python, session, session-cookies, fastapi, starlette

I need to create a session for authentication in the `session_set` endpoint. However, for some reason, the session is still being created in the `session_info` endpoint. How to make a session created only in `session_set`? Otherwise, I have a new session in the response with each request.

Here is my code:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string", max_age=None)


@app.get("/a")
async def session_set(request: Request):
    request.session["my_var"] = "1234"
    return 'ok'


@app.get("/b")
async def session_info(request: Request):
    my_var = request.session.get("my_var", None)
    return my_var


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('http-session:app', port=5000, reload=True)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [Middleware](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/) to override the `session` value in the [`Response` cookies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-cookies/) (check the [documentation in Starlette](https://www.starlette.io/responses/#set-cookie) as well) every time a new request arrives; hence, the `session` will remain the same.

**Note:** Remember to declare your custom middleware, **after** adding the [`SessionMiddleware`](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#sessionmiddleware) to the `app` instance, as the order that endpoints/sub-applications are defined in your application **matters**, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73113792/17865804) (see the relevant [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#order-matters) as well).

##### Working Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="some-random-string")

@app.middleware("http")
async def some_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = await call_next(request)
    session = request.cookies.get('session')
    if session:
        response.set_cookie(key='session', value=request.cookies.get('session'), httponly=True)
    return response
 
@app.get("/a")
def func_a(request: Request):
    request.session["my_var"] = "1234"
    print(request.cookies.get('session'))
    return 'OK'

@app.get("/b")
def func_b(request: Request):
    my_var = request.session.get("my_var", None)
    print(request.cookies.get('session'))
    return my_var
```

Comment: Can i do sessions in fastapi like this https://prnt.sc/klQyAwad0iKb ? Without set-cookie in response headers. Or this impossible?