# JWT (XSS) vs Cookies (CSRF)?

Tags: cookies, jwt, fastapi, csrf, xss

I'm a Python backend developer at a start-up. Recently, I was asked to build the authentication system for APIs, and I implemented a token-based authentication mechanism (JWT) using the FastAPI framework of Python. Then the frontend team asked me to explain how they're supposed to store the token, and I said they can store it on local storage since browsers don't have a built-in feature for JWTs like cookies. But then I realized that it allows attackers to perform XSS-to-ATO (Account Takeover) attacks. Then I searched for a more secure way to store JWTs and found out about storing JWTs in httpOnly cookies. Now, XSS to ATO is prevented, but now I need to deal with CSRF attacks, which is no big deal, but if I'm going to store JWTs in cookies, then what's the point of using JWT?

**Here are two options in my mind:**

1. Use JWT, store it in local storage, and apply a robust CSP (Content Security Policy) so even if an XSS pops up, attackers can't exploit the vulnerability.
2. Use Cookies and prevent CSRF (I think referer header checks should be enough, but I'll also use the cookie attributes as well).

Which option should I pick and if you have any other ideas, please let me know.

Comment: The referrer should _never_ be relied on, for _anything_.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73599289/17865804), among others, provides details on that subject.

Comment: Another option might be the `SameSite Cookies` explained [here](https://dev.to/pcreem/use-httponly-samesite-secure-cookie-token-on-graphql-server-local-experiment-9od) to store the JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

using to local storage to saving jwt token is not safe way(xss attack) but combine cookie with csrf token is safe way to handling attack. if you accurace to your request in each sending to backend you can see the  csrf will be change and will be check with backend if you use validate csrf on each of your action so this can decrease the vulnerability.
this may can help you about cookies :
[https://www.cookiescan.com/what-are-website-cookies-and-where-are-they-stored/#:~:text=Cookies%20are%20usually%20small%20text,directory%20or%20program%20data%20subfolders](https://www.cookiescan.com/what-are-website-cookies-and-where-are-they-stored/#:%7E:text=Cookies%20are%20usually%20small%20text,directory%20or%20program%20data%20subfolders).